# Google Streetview Images in infowindow

Tags: postgresql, carto, google-street-view

I have followed the instructions on this blog post on adding streetview images to the infowindow:
http://blog.cartodb.com/a-picture-is-worth-1-000-attributes-infowindows-with/

I can do it without a problem and the images work well, however while the SQL query is running I cannot add new points to my map while in the CartoDB editor.

Is there a way around this. I would like to show the images but also be able to add points.

I am using the SQL query below. Would the solution be to change it to a query which actually writes the data into my table permanently for every new point I create, rather than just querying it? If so what would that script look like?

(Sorry about my limited SQL knowledge)

```
SELECT *, 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x190&location='||
ST_Y((the_geom))||','||ST_X((the_geom))||'&sensor=false&fov=110' as image
FROM table_2012_entire_tree_down_complaints_sandy
```

If this is possible then would a Google reverse geocode also be possible, utilising a similar script?

Answer (score 1):

When a SQL query is applied, the dataset becomes read-only mode in order to avoid the lose of data: imagine that you're running an aggregative query and you edit a value in your table, that would be a missmatch between the results of the query and the actual contents of your data.

In this case I'd recommend to use the query in the map and go directly to the dataset to access the data, where your query won't be applied.

If you need to edit something specific in a very big table, notice that you can edit table values while filtering through the filter options (as the filters do not perform computations/operations on the data and there's no possibility for discordance in this case).